# Need some hint for a coffescript/jQuery iteration

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I tried

```
alert x for x in $("p").text()
```

to alert paragraph by paragraph... but instead it alert letter by letter (lol, wtf...). Then I tried this

```
alert x.text() for x in $("p")
```

but it doesnt work either. Can you help me to iterate for all the texts of paragraphs? Thank you in advance and happy new year!!!!

Comment: Would you tick an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the question and I realized how newbie Im, lol. The objects of jQuery are objects, not arrays, then when I do something like

```
alert x.text() for x in $("p")
```

x are the values of the object $('p') that is something different that thinking $('p') as a kind of array of paragraphs. Then the solution is something like this

```
for x,i in $('p')
  alert $('p').eq(i).text()
```

P.S.: maybe with the full documentation about the internal structure of the jQuery DOM I can try something different, but by now this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`alert x.innerText for x in $('p')`

How does this work? Firstly, let's transpile it to JS. According to the [CoffeeScript website, it transpile's this code to](http://coffeescript.org/#try:alert%20x.innerText%20for%20x%20in%20%24('p')):

```
var i, len, ref, x;

ref = $('p');
for (i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
  x = ref[i];
  alert(x.innerText);
}
```

Proof that this transpiled code works: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/do8bch73/).

What does this code do?

Firstly, we call the jQuery library passing a selector `p`, which will fetch all the paragraphs to the `ref` variable as an object.

In the loop, depending on the number of paragraphs fetched, it will loop that many times. The variable `x` is given the value of the current `p` in the object. Then, we alert the `innerText` property of the the `x` object which represents the `p` in HTML.

Comment: Doesnt work either... it iterates letter by letter :(

Comment: @Masacroso Got the problem. Try now.

Comment: @Masacroso `innerHTML` works perfectly for me. Try that.

Comment: Yeah, last thing is so close. The problem is now that it maintain internal HTML tags. Maybe appending after .innerText may work.

Comment: @Masacroso Yeah, I have updated the code in the post for `innerText`. Feel free to tick this answer if this satisfies you. :)

Comment: @Masacroso It should. Check the code I gave. Don't do `x.innerHTML.innerText`, just `x.innerText`, also it is case sensitive so be careful.